# Looking for a sample docker file - how do I install a jdbc driver into a Linux docker container

Tags: docker, jdbc, dockerfile, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-aks

Regarding fetching the data from the snowflake database table and store it to Kafka topic through JDBC Connector.

1. We want to deploy a docker image having JDBC and all other required configurations installed on our existing AKS cluster.
2. Docker image will make request to Snowflake database to get data.
3. Again, using JDBC we will populate data in Confluent Topics.
   Following depicts the above-mentioned steps,
   [image]

I am looking for a sample docker file which will have the configuration details to install a jdbc driver into a Linux docker container and configuration details to connect to the snowflake database.   Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the java environment you want to use, but the following is for openjdk.

The general example is given in the openjdk [doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk).

It requires just one change - downloading the Snowflake JDBC driver.

```shell
FROM openjdk:11
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

RUN curl -L -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/snowflake/snowflake-jdbc/3.13.25/snowflake-jdbc-3.13.25.jar

RUN javac TestJdbc.java

CMD java -cp .:snowflake-jdbc-3.13.25.jar TestJdbc
```

Of course the above will work for a simple one-file application in the TestJdbc.java. You will need to modify it to be sure all your files and dependencies are copied into the container and the class path is correctly set. You can do a quick test with an example code from the Snowflake [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#examples).

I am simplifying it even more to show here:

```java
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestJdbc
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws Exception
  {
    String url = "jdbc:snowflake://"+System.getenv("ACCOUNT")+".snowflakecomputing.com/?user="+System.getenv("USERNAME")+"&password="+System.getenv("PASSWORD")+"&db="+System.getenv("DATABASE")+"&schema="+System.getenv("SCHEMA")+"&warehouse="+System.getenv("WAREHOUSE")+"&role="+System.getenv("ROLE");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()");
    res.next();
    System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    conn.close();
  }
}
```

And then build and run with all necessary env-vars for the database like `docker run -e USERNAME=example -e PASSWORD=pass ... jdbc-image`.

I hope the examples and the docs will give you an idea how to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the details aek.  Thank you for the code too.  is this sample code to test the connectivity from my local machine and to verify if everything is ok?    To deploy it to AKS, I believe the docker file with configurations  with out the code will do the work.  Correct me if my understanding is not right ?

Comment: @VamKris Yes, with this examples you should be able to build a container with a simple java code on your local machine. When you run it, it will send a small select query just to test if everything is built and connected properly. The dockerfile contains steps to build and run your actual application, these are not snowflake specific and depend on your actual application. Snowflake specific part of the java code should be similar to the example

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.Hope I can use .Net code to test.

Comment: Hi aek, 
 is there a way to include the connection string JDBC URL and the Query in the docker file itself which will help for the connectivity/data fetch  instead building container with code.  please advise ?

Comment: @VamKris you can use environment variables for that. I've updated my answer showing how you can set the env variables in the docker file, and build the JDBC connection string in the app code. Of course you can replace it, by just setting one env variable with the connection string, in use this var in your code.

Comment: Thank you aek for your inputs. I have 2 questions. 1) I am new to Java how can I make the above work in .Net  2) once the data is fetched from Snowflake database using same JDBC connector how will I be able to populate data to Confluent  kafkaTopics.

Comment: @VamKris 1) "Confluent" doesn't matter here. They publish a C# client, and that's it; it works for any Kafka cluster. 2) JDBC **does not** work with C#, so you cannot use that Snowflake driver, anyway

Comment: @OneCricketeer  Thank you for the response. 
I am new to Docker environment. will the Docker file supports to have the instructions like below(step 1, step 2, step 3)  and performs all the steps.  correct me if my understanding is wrong? 

#step 1 download the jdbc 
FROM openjdk:11 RUN curl -L -O repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/snowflake/snowflake-jdbc/3.13.25/… 

#step 2 environment variables to connect to database. 

#step 3 query the data from the table and copy the data and push it to kafka topic.

Comment: That'll work sure (you'd want to use Maven/Gradle, not curl), but you can do all those same steps with [dotnet-core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/introduction) and C#  Snowflake driver using Nuget instead of Java + JDBC...

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for clarifying.  Long story short, I have already executed a usecase using "dotnet-core and C# Snowflake driver using Nuget". Now I am working on executing another usecase with out using dotnet-core and C#.  I have heard that JDBC connector will help to connect to snowflake database and fetch the data. If possible can you please help me with inputs on Maven/Gradle  so that I can try to achieve all the 3 steps through the Docker file.

Comment: @VamKris C# Driver works the exact same as JDBC. I suggest you open a new question clarifying why you need JDBC, and what you've already tried, as it does not relate to Docker

Comment: I found the solution using jdbc connector   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75270866/snowflake-to-kafka-topic-using-jdbcsourceconnector-timezone-issue/75330989#75330989