# Snowflake to kafka topic using JdbcSourceConnector timezone issue

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

I am working on POC Usecase setting up JDBC connector to fetch the data from Snowflake database and push it to a Kafka topic. I am running into timezone related issue and the exception is `Kafka Connect Date type should not have any time fields set to non-zero values`.

I am using a snowflake view to fetch the data and the view column data types are as below.  LOADDATE is timestamp column and its datatype is TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) where NTZ is no time zone which is UTC.

```
AGENTFIRSTNAME    VARCHAR(200)
AGENTMIDDLENAME    VARCHAR(200)
AGENTLASTNAME    VARCHAR(200)
AGENTNAME    VARCHAR(400)
AGENTKEY    NUMBER(38,0)
ISAGENCY    BOOLEAN
NPN            VARCHAR(50)
AGENTNUMBER    VARCHAR(100)
AGENTSTATE    VARCHAR(50)
VUENAME            VARCHAR(100)
GROUPNAME    VARCHAR(200)
TYPENAME    VARCHAR(80)
SUBMITDATE    DATE
CONFNUMBER    VARCHAR(100)
SRCE            VARCHAR(100)
INSFIRSTNAME    VARCHAR(16777216)
INSLASTNAME    VARCHAR(16777216)
INSCITY            VARCHAR(16777216)
INSSTATE    VARCHAR(16777216)
INSBIRTHDATE    DATE
LOADDATE    TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)
```

I have referred stackoverflow and online forums and To fix the issue `Kafka Connect Date type should not have any time fields set to non-zero values`, suggestion is to to setup in connector config db.timezone parameter:

I have run the query `SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'TIMEZONE' IN ACCOUNT;` in the snowflake query window to find out timezone and it returned America/Los_Angeles.
[image]

I have tried using America/Los_Angeles as timezone, then I also tried using UTC as timezone  in my sfconnector.json  and rebuilt the docker image and then I have run the docker container but so far I did not messages in Kafka topic.

I have attached the Exception in containerlog file,  DataException: `Kafka Connect Date type should not have any time fields set to non-zero values.`

Exception:

```
2023-01-27 09:34:50  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig)
2023-01-27 09:35:01 [2023-01-27 15:35:01,039] ERROR Error encountered in task jdbc-snowflake-source-0. Executing stage 'VALUE_CONVERTER' with class 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter', where source record is = SourceRecord{sourcePartition={protocol=1, table=DEV_ED.DBO.VW_CENTERENROLLMENT_IC}, sourceOffset={}} ConnectRecord{topic='VW_CENTERENROLLMENT_IC', kafkaPartition=null, key=null, keySchema=null, value=Struct{AGENTFIRSTNAME=GRECHEN,AGENTMIDDLENAME=LYNN,AGENTLASTNAME=SOWELL,AGENTNAME=GRECHEN LYNN SOWELL,AGENTKEY=690042,ISAGENCY=false,NPN=8991475,AGENTNUMBER=8991475,AGENTSTATE=MI,VUENAME=POE,GROUPNAME=Ana,TYPENAME=PDP,SUBMITDATE=2020-10-20,CONFNUMBER=SMVW8PDYWC,SOURCE=Sunfest,INSFIRSTNAME=Mary,INSLASTNAME=Hoefler,INSCITY=Grand Rapids,INSSTATE=MI,INSBIRTHDATE=1970-09-21,LOADDATE=2020-12-09 16:29:51.0}, valueSchema=Schema{VW_CENTERENROLLMENT_IC:STRUCT}, timestamp=null, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=)}. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter)
2023-01-27 09:35:01 org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Kafka Connect Date type should not have any time fields set to non-zero values.
```

Attached are the sfconnector config and full ContainerLog.

sfconnector config:

```
{
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
"mode": "timestamp",    
"timestamp.column.name": "LOADDATE",
"db.timezone": "America/Los_Angeles", 
"numeric.mapping": "best_fit",
"errors.log.include.messages": "true",    
"tasks.max": "1",
"validate.non.null": "false",   
"connection.url": "jdbc:snowflake://dp8881.central-us.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/?warehouse=ED_WH&db=DEV_ED&role=FR_IC_ANLYST&schema=DBO&user=IC_SERVICE_ACT&private_key_file=/tmp/snowflake_key.p8",
"errors.log.enable": "true", 
"table.whitelist": "DEV_ED.DBO.VW_CENTERENROLLMENT_IC",
"table.types": "VIEW"
```

}

Thanks
Vamshi

Answer (score 0):

While troubleshooting the issue, I was able to see that the issue is caused due to Timestamp and Date columns in the view. I had to convert the timestamp and all DATE columns using convert_timezone to UTC in the view. Updated by using convert_timezone:

convert_timezone('UTC', Loaddate) as Loaddate, convert_timezone('UTC', Submitdate) as Submitdate, convert_timezone('UTC', Insbirthdate) as Insbirthdate.

After the above view updates, The Kafka topic is created and are messages stored to it but observation is that all the three convert_timezone columns data i.e. (Loaddate, Submitdate,  Insbirthdate)  are missing/not recorded in the Kafka topic.

Per the Docker Container Logs, the warning/error message is recorded as  "TIMESTAMPTZ not currently supported"

But when I converted these three date columns to CHAR then those values are also stored to Kafka topic.

Thanks
Vamshi

Answer (score 0):

Thought to share the solution for my above post:

I was using latest version of the Jdbc Driver 3.13.26 But with this newest version of Jdbc driver, there are Timestamp issues. The type here comes as TIMESTAMP_TZ, which is not supported by GenericDialect of JDBC, hence we get the exceptions like

a)WARN JDBC type 2014 (TIMESTAMPIZ) not currently supported.
b)TIMESTAMP column not found.

In older version 3.13.16, it comes as TIMESTAMP.

So I have used 3.13.16 Jdbc driver installation command in my Dockerfile and re-built the Docker image which fixed the issues in my POC Usecase.

Thanks
Vamshi